# Android: Custom Dialog unwanted extra space

Tags: java, android, dialog

I'm having an issue with my custom dialog, it shows empty space at the right side when I set the width and hight to wrap_content. I don't want to use match_parent because the picture will be bigger and the layout will not be right when I do landscape.

[image]

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/share_layout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/rl4">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/media_share_img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/step_one" />

            <Button
                android:background="@drawable/red_button"
                android:id="@+id/media_share_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/dialog_button_share"
                style="@style/button_text"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/media_share_img"
                android:layout_below="@+id/media_share_img"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/media_share_img" />

        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

java:

```
    View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_share, null);
 dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(dialogView)
           /* .setNeutralButton(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_button_close), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })*/.create();
            /*
            .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).*/
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: You could try adding `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your ImageView.

Comment: didn't fix my problem ...

Comment: Only two view try using single linear layout with vertical orientation.

Comment: Man I wish there was a solution to this, been searching for hours now